# jQuery Single Page app dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jQuery Single Page app that works but not the way I want it to.
I have a list of counties that is read from a JSON file (the list can be filtered). When one is chosen, it appears as a hyperlink that links to another "page" with a town from that county (the "page" is actually just a div in the same page). The trouble is I have to manually create the divs beforehand. E.g if there are five items in the JSON file and I want to add one more, I have to manually add an extra div in the page.
It works OK for the counties, I can add extra counties to the JSON and it builds an extra hyperlink but for the "page" it links to I need to create a new div in the html. When I create the divs dynamically (under the inner "each" in the Javascript code) nothing happens when you click on the link as the div does not exist in the html.
Is there a solution to this? (see code below)

```
HTML (with js):



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"></script>
    <title>How to Parse a JSON file using jQuery</title>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">   

<a href="#myKoolPanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-navigation ui-btn-icon-left" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
   <div data-role="content">
        <div id="results">
            <ul id="mynewlist" data-role ="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true">


            </ul>

        </div>
   </div>

    <div data-role="panel" class="cd-panel from-left" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal" id="myKoolPanel" data-theme="a">

                    <ul id ="myul" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a" style="margin-top:-16px;" class="nav-search">

                        <li>
                            <a href="Test1.html">Towns in Ireland</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Test2.html">Map of Ireland</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

    </div>

 </div>

    <script>

       $(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {

        var items = [];
         var z=0;
        $.each( data, function( i, item ) {  
            z=z+1;

             items.push('<li><a href=#textcontainer'+z+'>' + i +  '</a></li>');
             $.each(item, function(property, value) {

                $('#textcontainer'+z).append(value);  
            });        


                });

                $('#mynewlist').append( items.join('') );
            });

        });


    </script>
<div id ="textcontainer1"> </div>
<div id ="textcontainer2"> </div> 
<div id ="textcontainer3"> </div>
<div id ="textcontainer4"> </div>
<div id ="textcontainer5"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file:

```
{


        "Kerry": {
            "town": "Kenmare"

        },


        "Cork": {
            "town": "Mallow"

        },


        "Limerick": {
           "town": "Charleville"

        },


        "Meath": {
            "town": "Trim"

        },


        "Waterford": {
            "town": "Lismore"

        }

}
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle out of this?

Comment: I can but the JSON file is a local file, I don't have anywhere to upload it to.

Comment: This seems to work but it only adds the HTML once (on pageload first time). If I change what I want appended (e.g. I change 'John' to 'Kevin') and I refresh the page it doesn;t change the html from 'John' to 'Kevin'.     $(document).ready(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').append('<div>johnKEVIN</div>');

Comment: No actually it doesn't work, sorry

Comment: Hi @leesider. You can put the JSON file contents into the JavaScript panel of jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Using AngularJs you can solve it.

Define js file as below

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
var data;
$scope.data =[{
         "name":"Kerry",
        "town": "Kenmare"
    },
    {
        "name":"Cork",
        "town": "Mallow"
    },
    {
       "name":"Limerick",
       "town": "Charleville"

    },
    {
        "name":"Meath",
        "town": "Trim"
    },
    {
        "name":"Waterford",
        "town": "Lismore"
    }] ;
  });
```

HTML file code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"> </script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="fileName.js">     </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div ng-repeat="d in data">
         {{d.name}} : {{d.town}}
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: if you want to add inside div then use                                                                        <div ng-repeat="d in data">
        <div id="{{$index}}">                                                                {{d.name}} : {{d.town}}
     </div>  </div>

Comment: Yes that would do it Flash but I would need to hardcode the JSON into the scope.data (essentially having the same information twice). However I may be able to get the scope.data to read from the json file.

Comment: @leesider then assigned json file to $scope.data or store to localStorage

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work as with ng-controller and repeat, the html does not appear on the page so in the url it is not possible to place #divid to the end and then jump to that div. I think the only way to do it is to edit the html directly with an jquery, ajax and php

Comment: @leesider  if your json file is local then u can modified it.